# Flash playback in G-Chrome consumes more CPU than in other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

In my observation, on my computer, it seems that when I play back a flash based video (y-tube, or anything, especially in HD), the Chrome tab process consumes almost entirely one of my cores. When I watch videos in other browsers, they're seem to be finer.

Is this anomaly related to the way how Chrome's plugin surface rendering works? Is there a software way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any way to fix this, but it sounds like there is more overhead when it comes to the flash player because of the process architecture. It seems to me that because each tab is it's own sandbox there is an overhead when including the instance of flash. Why it is using so much of your processor is beyond me. This is something to ask on the google chrome [discussion groups](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-discuss).

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the discussion group, but I'm to addicted to the SO family. I will keep the question open for a bit more.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer at the discussion groups since google chrome is still (relatively) early in development.